# Kubuntu 22.04 won't boot after a clean install

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kubuntu, hang

After a clean install of Kubuntu 22.04, I get these messages and computer just hangs infinitely:

```
[0.149135] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
[5.427817] usb 1-6: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81
[5.440863] usb 1-6: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
[5.464184] usb 1-6: 4:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x2
```

- ASUS Prime Z270-P
- Intel i7-7700
- Nvidia GTX 1070
- Partition style: GPT
- BIOS Mode: UEFI
- I used Ventoy to create a bootable USB flash drive
- Fast Startup disabled on Widows 10, which is installed on a separate SSD device
- Linux Mint LMDE 4 used to work just fine for over 2 years on the same SDD device where I'm now trying to run Kubuntu 22.04

The only thing that works is Ctrl+Alt+Delete, which restarts machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Grub menu, I pressed 'e' on my keyboard and replaced 'quiet splash' with 'nomodeset'. After that, I used `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, which seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: That means you did not use Safe Boot and choose to install the optional restricted drivers which would install the nVidia driver. From terminal you can install the default nVidia driver, and then do not use nomodeset. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` Best to run after system fully updated. Also if you have installed one nVidia driver and change, you must purge old driver or you get conflicts. A new driver, does not deleted old one.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, that seems to have fixed it.